# Azure LogicAppsからAzure VM接続をして、curlコマンドを実行する。

Tags: azure

AzureのLogicApps機能を使用して、AzureVM（Linux）の中に作成したシェルスクリプトを10分おきに実行して、実行結果をストレージアカウントに書き込みたいです。
LogicAppsだけで完結させたく、他のリソースを使わずに実現できるかを知っている方がいましたら、教えていただきたいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なお、今までに実行しようとした手順として、以下のサイトをやってみました。
https://qiita.com/shingo_kawahara/items/fffd748309fa9bb5ab57
→こちらのサイトだと、シェルスクリプトをVM内で定期的に動かさないといけないため、LogicAppsを引き金として、すべて完結させることができるのが一番の目的です。
何か、知っている方がいらっしゃたら、情報提供をお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

こんにちは。

HTTP で Virtual Mchine の Run Command を実行してやってはどうでしょうか。
これだと Functions や Automation など追加のサービスを使わない方法といえるかなーと。

シェルスクリプトをリモート実行したいだけであればこのように直接接続しなくても良いかなと思いました。

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/rest/api/compute/virtual-machines/run-command?tabs=HTTP#runcommandinput

例えば、Linuxマシン上に hoge.sh というスクリプトを配置した場合だと以下のような感じです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: いわさ様
コメントありがとうございます。

早速、いただいたものに関して検証を実施しておりますが、認証で引っかかってしまうため、現状マネージドIDのところを調査中です。

また、初学のため、うまく理解できていない点があるのですが、こちらをLogicAppsで実施する際には、対象のVMにApacheが入っている必要があり、443ポートがLISTENになっている必要があるという認識でいいのでしょうか…？


まずは認証に関して解消されないといけないため、引き続き調査に努めたいと思います。
貴重なお時間をありがとうございました。

Comment: 実際にLogic Apps から仮想マシン上のスクリプトを実行してみました。以下もご確認ください。
https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/azure-logc-apps-run-script-vm/

スクリプトで何をしたいかですが、Apacheは不要です。
この記事ではcurlを実行しているので、curlは必要です。

Comment: いわさ様
サイト、閲覧させていただきました。
実際に同じ設定で実施してみましたが、マネージドIDあたりでひっかかってしまっています。
LogicAppsのマネージド ID を有効化しているのですが、他の認証関連で引っかかっていると思われます…！（仮想マシン側のマネージドＩＤの有効化など）
しかし、実際にLogicAppsで仮想マシンにあるスクリプトを実行できるという最初の目的の方法をいわさ様のおかげで知ることができました。本当にありがとうございます。